# Sum Booleans and then display only over a certain count

Tags: libreoffice, radix

I've been banging my head against the wall a while.

I have a table that has `DwgID` (`integer`) and `Current` (`boolean`) as part of the table.

What I want to do is filter just the `DwgID`'s that have more than 1 `Current` selected.

This code gives me the count correctly:

```
`SELECT "DwgID", SUM( CASE WHEN "Current" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) "Current" FROM "tblRev" GROUP BY "DwgID"`
```

But if I try to add a criteria where the `Current Count is > 1`, it fails with a data content could not be loaded.

```
`SELECT "DwgID", SUM( CASE WHEN "Current" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) "Current" FROM "tblRev" GROUP BY "DwgID" HAVING ( ( SUM( CASE WHEN "Current" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) > 1 ) )`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your code to be 4 spaces before the code lines individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose a different alias because `Current` is the column name.  Let's call it `NumCurrent` instead.

```sql
SELECT "DwgID", SUM( CASE WHEN "Current" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) "NumCurrent" FROM "tblRev" GROUP BY "DwgID" HAVING ( ( SUM( CASE WHEN "Current" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) > 1 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you.  Exactly what I was looking for.  I knew it was something stupid I was doing :)